# How do I find all questions/answers per a tag?

Tags: support, api-v2, api, documentation

Would also be good if I could also find the *top* questions/answers in a particular tag - i.e. questions tagged with *Ruby* or *PHP*.

Per [the docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs?tab=type#docs) the only thing I can see that will return questions in a particular tag is [FAQs by tag](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/faqs-by-tags).

There anyway for me to retrieve just the questions & answers in a specific tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/questions` take's a semi-colon delimited list of tags in the `tagged` parameter.  If `tagged` is set, questions returned will have all the passed tags (ie. it's an AND operator).

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=votes&tagged=python&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true

^ for example, [`that query`](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions?order=desc&sort=votes&tagged=python&filter=default&site=stackoverflow) returns all questions tagged with python, highest voted questions first.

`/search` and `/search/advanced` expose a `tagged` parameter that is an OR instead of an AND, though those methods return fewer results than `/questions`.

Comment: What about answers & comments? I am using Serel, and I figured out the best way to achieve this for questions is something like this: `Serel::Question.search.tagged('Ruby').pagesize(10).sort('votes')`. But answers won't allow the `search` method for whatever reason. Also, how do I receive more results than just `pagesize(100)`? Once I try going to `101` it returns `0`. I also tried `has_more` and that didn't work. For instance, I was trying to retrieve all the tags by doing `Serel::Tag.total` and that returned `NoMethodError: undefined method 'total' for #<Serel::Relation:0x007f8d53a8fab0>`

Comment: Only questions have tags, if you want answers to tagged questions you have to come at them from a question direction.  For `/questions` or `/search` you can add `question.answers` to your [filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) to get the answers along with the question (as they're not included in the default filter).  `.total` likewise isn't included by default.  Maximum pagesize is 100, if you need more than 100 results you have to make multiple requests.

Comment: Ahh ok....so I guess the same thing applies to comments.

Comment: How do I get the number of tags on the system? I have gone through 1800 tags so far - are there really that many tags on SO?

Comment: @marcamillion As of today I see [1160 pages of tags](http://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=1160&tab=popular) on SO. At 30 tags each that is 34,800 tags total.