# Why API Version 2.2 returns null always while getting questions list?

Tags: support, questions, api-v2.2

The below 2 codes returns null always. How to get the list of questions using API Version 2.2?

1. ```
   Question thisPost = context.Official
   .StackApps
   .Questions.ById(1)
   .WithComments(true)
   .First();
   ```
2. ```
   var context = new ApiContext(apikey).Initialize(false);
   var site = context.Find("https://stackexchange.com/");

   var skysQuestions = site.Users.ById(1).Questions.ToList();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

1. You appear to be trying to use [Soapi.CS](https://stackapps.com/questions/386/soapi-cs-a-fully-relational-fluent-net-stack-exchange-api-client-library) -- which is way obsolete and using an old API version that no longer functions.  If you are going to use *.net*, try one of the more recent libraries like:

   - [StacMan](/questions/3411/stacman-net-client-for-stack-exchange-api-v2)
   - [ExchangeLinq](/questions/3363/exchangelinq-linq-query-provider-for-stack-exchange-api-v2-0)
   - [BridgeStack](/questions/2945/bridgestack-net-client-library-with-full-2-0-support)
   - [Stacky](/questions/6/stacky-a-net-client-library-full-support-for-api-v2-0)
2. This code: `.Questions.ById(1)` would fetch question #1, [**which has been deleted**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1/).
   The API will not fetch deleted questions.  When testing you need to check your requests against the site to see if they make sense.
3. If you have problems with a 3rd-party library, that's listed here on Stack Apps, do not post the report as a question -- since the issue is not with an official Stack Exchange product.

   **Post such 3rd-party problems as "answers" on the libraries question page.**  You can see an example of someone doing that with [this answer](https://stackapps.com/a/6839/7653).

Comment: Hi Adams, Thank you for your response. I just posted the query with sample question id. Also i tried to use the recent libraries you mentioned. But i can able to get the questions which are handled by corresponding concern. For example i have used BridgeStack library and its returns the questions which are handling by Bridgestack. can you please let me know how to get the questions based on tag name?

Comment: Melody, that's a separate question from this one and [has already been answered](http://stackapps.com/questions/3933/how-do-i-find-all-questions-answers-per-a-tag) in the general sense.  If you want to know how to do it using one of the libraries, then ask (as an "answer") in that library's announcement question, not here.  (PS: I don't use .net ;)